# how do we pass data from controller to view in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am starting in zend framework 1.11. How do we pass different $data value in view from controller to view like in codeigniter we pass like this.

```
$data['pass_one_thing'] = $this->model1->pass_all_mangoes();
$data['pass_another_thing'] = $this->model2->pass_all_oranges();
$this->load->view('viewfile', $data);
```

then in views we get values of $pass_one_thing and $pass_another_thing with foreach loops in same view file.

how do i pass from different model function in a same view ?

How do we get such thing in zend ? I am new to zend and bit confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be done pretty much the same:

```
$this->view->data = $data;
```

Or use the `assign` function:

```
$this->view->assign('data', $data);
```

edit: 
How do I pass from different model function in a same view 
Not exactly sure but taking your exact example:

```
$this->view->data['pass_one_thing'] = $this->model1->pass_all_mangoes();
$this->view->data['pass_another_thing'] = $this->model2->pass_all_oranges();
$this->load->view('viewfile', $data);
```

Then in your view  you would access these trough:

```
$this->data['pass_one_thing']
$this->data['pass_another_thing']
```

Comment: how do i pass from different model function in a same view ?

Comment: $this->view->fun1 = $this->model1->pass_all_mangoes(); $this->view->fun2 = $this->model2->pass_all_mangoes();

Answer (score 10):

You set it in your controller as:

```
$this->view->myVar = "something";
```

And then access it from the view:

```
echo $this->myVar;
```

Or using assign like Wesley said.